# Past participle agreement with the subject in the case of pronominal verbs

Tags: grammaire, accord, verbes-pronominaux

I've been solving exercices in a book called practice makes perfect (linked down below) 
And in the Plus-que parfait exercices (page 82,81. 10.2 Exercice. N.3, N.10) there are those two sentences which are really confusing me :

*Tu (se demander) ....... s'il était allergique.*
*Elles (s'écrire) ..... pendant des années.*

The answers ,according to the Answer Key, should be (t'etais demandé(e), s'étaient écrites) but I don't understand why there is an agreement here. I thought that reciprocal verbs which take an indirect object its past participle does not agree with the subject. And worth noting also that in the exercices of the Passe Composé there are those two similar sentence which have no agreement (page 63) :

*Ils se sont écrit de long lettres.*
*Nous nous sommes demandé pourquoi il était absent.*

And here's a part of the book explanation for the past participle agreement thing (page 62,63) :

"When reciprocal verbs take an indirect object in French, the past participle does not agree.

Ils se sont téléphoné.   They called each other.

Vous vous êtes parlé au téléphone.   You talked to each other on the phone.

Ils se sont écrit de longues lettres.   They wrote each other long letters."

[image: and here's the whole explanation as whenever I try to copy it, its format always gets messed up somehow]

Book link : ( https://archive.org/details/practice-makes-perfect-complete-french-grammar/page/n94 )

Note : please don't explain in french. My french isn't that advanced yet and it will be super hard to understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, there shouldn't be an agreement.

As you can see, both `t'` and `s'` are indirect objects here : *to whom did you ask* etc.?  *to whom did they write* ? etc.

As per the rule you quoted near the end of your post, *when reciprocal verbs take an indirect object, the past participle **does not** agree*.

Therefore it should be:

> Tu t'étais **demandé** s'il était allergique.
>
> Elles s'étaient **écrit** pendant des années.

Comment: That's so strange, I haven't seen any mistakes in that book so far let alone that's not only one but two.

Comment: Mistakes happen :) Looks like ils s'étaient trompés.

Answer (score 2):

The agreement in the case of "tu étais réveillé(e)" for example depends on the sex of the person who is talking/whose you are talking to (the subject). There is no *indirect object* here. It is a simple agreement like "tu es intelligente" when you are saying that to a girl.

The agreement in "elles s'étaient écrites pendant des années" (and so "tu t'étais demandé s'il était allergique" is different, because you can say "à qui / à quoi / de qui / …" after the object that means it is an *indirect object*. And in that case indeed the past participle never agrees, even with "être". As you may know, past participle agrees when "être" but not "avoir" in the case of a *direct object*.

Comment: so what is the difference between those two sentence and why there is an agreement in one of them and not the other even tho they've the same verb (se demander) : _Nous nous sommes demandé pourquoi il était absent._  _Tu t'etais demandé(e) s'il était allergique_

Comment: Shouldn't (se demander) don't agree in the seecond one as I can say : demander à quelqu'un.

Comment: As you can see in the first one (nous nous sommes demandé...) there is an *indirect object* with the reflexive pronoun.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I just didn't notice that it was in fact *se demander* as you said in your comment that's why I got confused ! But the rule as explained above is still correct even if it doesn't explicitely respond to your question.. I'm very sorry for that.

Comment: Never mind and as mcadorel said in his comment : misakes happen :)

Comment: You're right, thank you ;)

Comment: Sorry for bothering u again but there is that thing confusing me about your answer, u wrote " _The agreement you are talking about at the beginning depends....There is no indirect object here._ " and I reread and reread the begining part of my question but couldn't find any sentence that contains a direct object there even tho there was technically an agreement ,which why I posted this question, there wasn't a direct object .

Comment: Yeah because in fact it was my mistake and I was thinking about *demander* and not *se demander*. And please don't apologise, it's my fault actually :/ I've just corrected it.